# generalization of geometric series $ \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{p(k)} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, closed-form

I have been playing around with infinite series and I wondered if it is possible to find an expression for the series:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{p(k)}
$$
as a generalization of geometric series. $p(k)$ is an arbitrary polynomial.

Comment: As far as I know, (letting $x=10$ and $p=-k^2$), $1.1001000010000001\dots$ has no known closed form. It _is_ transcendental (and irrational), I think.

Comment: It's impossible to find for arbitrary polynomial, but for some particular it's possible to find a closed forms. Probably in some elliptic theta functions.

Comment: @m0nhawk I am interested in those particular cases. Do you know whether they are listed somewhere? (for [example](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483372/))

Comment: Do anyone know if such a series have a specific name ?