# Closed form solution for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^{\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I found this question [generalization of geometric series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993650/generalization-of-geometric-series-sum-k-0-infty-xpk), which asks about generalization of geometric series. Unfortunately, there is no answer and seems there is no such things.

Anyhow, in my case I don't have a polynomial exponent, but a specific case with square root:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^{\sqrt{n}},\ |a| < 1,$$

and in my case $a = e^{-t}$. Is there maybe some closed-form solution in terms of e.g. theta-function, or this is even more lost case than a polynomial one? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there is any closed form for this sum, and the answers in the linked question agree. I would be excited to be proven wrong, though ^_^

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks, I did not find that question. Yes, that will work. I close the question.